# The equivalent python exec/eval commands in C

Tags: python, c, exec, eval

is there a exec() / eval() function in C??

for example..

```
exec(printf(3 + 4))
```

or

```
eval(printf(3 + 4))
```

i've done this in python... but i don't know how to do this in C and C languages..

i understand that this might be harmful in python as it can take any input.. so to overcome that i came to C which is more strict

this is just a experiment i am curious to learn

an explaination would be appreiciated

i am using sublime text (just in case...:] )

Comment: No `C` standard doesn't support any such functions. `C` is strictly typed language.

Comment: No, there is not a built-in function like that. See discussion of why here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-method-in-C++-to-evaluate-strings-like-eval-in-Python#:~:text=C%2B%2B%20programs%20can%20run%20on,but%20it's%20a%20bit%20tricky. There are weird ways to do something similar, but they are slow and not worth the trouble: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091681/writing-eval-in-c

Comment: I am not sure tha C have this built in functions like. In C language, if you wish to `execute` some code you need to `fork()` and `execv` (family of executions) or to execute function by spawning a `thread` and let him do the job.
Or to `load` dynamic library, `SO`

Comment: Adam do you have a link / example to use fork() and execv ()?

Comment: i don't know how to spawn thread , load either.... kind of a begginer in c..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a simplified Lisp and in Lisp there is the [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval)/[apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply) paradigm.  In C this paradigm exists only inside the compiler.  The compilation system of C uses eval/apply, also called the [Maxwell equations of software](http://www.michaelnielsen.org/ddi/lisp-as-the-maxwells-equations-of-software/).  But at user level you do not interact with eval/apply, only if you write/develop in C a compiler for a language you cope with.

So in C you need to implement this yourself, in case you develop some language that is Turing complete (a Turing machine is equivalent with eval+apply cycle).

Comment: Interesting reference, "Maxwell equations of software"

Comment: its going to be difficult I_I

Answer (score 1):

An `eval()` function is typical of *interpreter based languages*. An interpreter is a "compiler on the fly" that interprets (hence its name) the program text and executes the program commands immediately.

An interpreter based language requires a program to be running that can read the program text and execute its instructions.

C is a *compiler based language* which means that the program text is translated "off-line" into an executable format that can run *without* a program to interpret the program text.

Because C does not have such an interpreter program running (and so the program does not have a language system "on board"), it has no way to interpret C program text in an `eval` function. For that reason, such functions do not exist in C.