# Undefined reference error from a makefile for a Fortran code with HDF5

Tags: makefile, fortran, hdf5, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile a Fortran 90 code that uses HDF5. For that purpose, I am using the following Makefile:

```
# Location of HDF5 binaries (with include/ and lib/ underneath)
HDF5 = /fs/posgrado16/other0/guido/libraries/hdf5/serial
# Compiler
FC        = gfortran
# ------ No machine-specific paths/variables after this  -----
FORTRANLIB=-I$(HDF5)/include $(HDF5)/lib/libhdf5_fortran.a

FSOURCE = h5_crtgrpar.f90
OBJECTS = $(FSOURCE:.f90=.o)
EXECUTABLE = $(FSOURCE:.f90=.exe)
LIBSHDF = $(FORTRANLIB) $(HDF5)/lib/libhdf5.a


all:$(EXECUTABLE)


$(EXECUTABLE):$(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBSHDF)

$(OBJECTS):$(FSOURCE)
    $(FC) -c $@ $< $(LIBSHDF)


.PHONY : clean

 clean:
    rm -f $(FSOURCE) $(OBJECTS) *.h5
```

But, I get the following error:

```
$ make -f Makefilef 
gfortran -o h5_crtgrpar.exe h5_crtgrpar.o -I/fs/posgrado16/other0/guido       /libraries/hdf5/serial/include /fs/posgrado16/other0/guido/libraries/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5_fortran.a /fs/posgrado16/other0/guido/libraries /hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.a 
/fs/posgrado16/other0/guido/libraries/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.a(H5PL.o): In    function `H5PL_term_interface':
H5PL.c:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/fs/posgrado16/other0/guido/libraries/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.a(H5PL.o): In   function `H5PL_load':
H5PL.c:(.text+0x477): undefined reference to `dlsym'
H5PL.c:(.text+0x5be): undefined reference to `dlopen'
H5PL.c:(.text+0x5d7): undefined reference to `dlsym'
H5PL.c:(.text+0x704): undefined reference to `dlclose'
H5PL.c:(.text+0x789): undefined reference to `dlerror'
H5PL.c:(.text+0x960): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [h5_crtgrpar.exe] Error 1
```

I have no idea what the error is. Probably, there is something wrong with my Makefile.

Comment: Welcome, be sure to read the [tour] and [ask]. For all Fortran questions use tag [tag:fortran]. Fortran 90 is just one version. File .f90 does not mean Fortran 90, but free-form file of any version but the exact version is completely unimportant without the code.

Comment: To understand what *Undefined reference* is please see [tag:undefined-reference], it is very  important to know that.

Comment: Don't you need `-lz` also?

Comment: Hey all, I believe that this is not a duplicate. Using HDF5 is a typical "Fortran computing" use case and the way the question is presented here is more likely to pop up in google searches than the suggested duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicated question! The question marked as the answer is too general and does not provide the answer, it just gives possible reasons causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile Fortran code with HDF5 enabled, you can replace

```
FC        = gfortran
```

by

```
FC        = h5fc
```

and skip all the hdf5 flags, as the `h5fc` wrapper will take care of those.

If you have some specific reason of calling the compiler by its name, you can learn about what flags are needed by calling

```
h5fc -show
```

that will show you what flags are added to the compiler.

On my computer (linux with gfortran), the result is:

```
gfortran -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5hl_fortran.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_hl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_fortran.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.a -Wl,-z,relro -lpthread -lz -ldl -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

Often you can get by with less flags than that, which you can find with some experimentation.

Given the error message you report, you lack the `-ldl` flags that enables linking of the dynamic linking library, see for isntance this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146525/meaning-of-library-dl-in-gcc/19146557#19146557).

Comment: Sorry, but there's no way I want to use a custom wrapper just for including hdf5. The `h5fc -show` is useful, but (in my opinion) only for diagnosing the original problem.

Comment: I personally use cmake and the FindHDF5 utility. For small projects, I use h5fc and see no issue with it.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, using the output of h5fc -show in the variable FORTRANLIB solved the problem.