# Dynamic loading DLL in C++ for Linux Platform

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying a Create a Linux C++ project using the same header and `.cpp` files from a Windows C++ project using Visual Studio. I am using below function to load a DLL dynamically in Windows

```cpp
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibraryA(sDllPath.c_str());
GetPluginInfoList GetInfoList = (GetPluginInfoList)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "GetPluginInfoList");
```

I think these functions hail from `<windows.h>`

When it comes to Linux C++ project I am not getting those functionalities. 
For Linux C++, what is the replacement for `HINSTANCE` and `LoadLibraryA`?

Comment: You're looking for `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

Comment: google => dlopen

Comment: Note that C++ has name mangling so the routines need an extern "C" interface see https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/

Comment: You also could look at Boost.DLL: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html

Comment: Thank you all I think above comments solved my problem :-)

Comment: @HariSankarvm in the spirit of this Q&A site, it would be great if you answered your own question with your findings.

Comment: Yes @0xC0000022L I have posted the solution.

Comment: @Quentin, When I build the project, it is showing error linke  ***Undefined reference to dlopen*** can you help me to solve this.

Comment: @HariSankarvm you need to [link with the `dl` library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146525/meaning-of-library-dl-in-gcc).

Answer (score 2):

I am posting my answer here. Thanks everyone for the support

```
typedef CPluginInfoList(*GetPluginInfoList)(void);



#if _WINDLL
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibraryA(sDllPath.c_str());

#else
    void* hGetProcIDDLL = dlopen(sDllPath.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);

#endif


#if _WINDLL
    GetPluginInfoList GetInfoList = (GetPluginInfoList)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "GetPluginInfoList");
#else
    GetPluginInfoList GetInfoList = (GetPluginInfoList)dlsym(hGetProcIDDLL, "GetPluginInfoList");
#endif


GetInfoList(); //Function Call
```

Comment: Remember that there is a dlclose if you wish to fix memory leaks on program closure.